# PDF contains A4 pages shrunk to A5. How can I increase back to A4?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have a PDF of A4 pages but on each page the "image"/content has been shrunk to A5.

What is the best way to "expand" the content (proportionally) so it is A4?

Preferably freeware but I can try Adobe Acrobat Pro if needed.

Comment: What is your goal? For printing it doesn't matter whether its A4 or A5, just use the common "Enlarge to page size" option when printing. And when viewing it in a PDF viewer there will also be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In Acrobat, under edit PDF find the crop tool. Draw a box around your page, and Enter. In the dialog box that opens on the bottom left is Change Page Size. Select custom and change the page to the size you want.

I have done this within a page with Acrobat DC Pro, but it will also work to change page size.

Reference material:

[Change Adobe page size](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/change-pdf-page-size-using-acrobat-dc/m-p/8017295#M24131)

> To use the crop tool, you need to use two steps: you have to enlarge
> the page first and the crop it down to the target size. The problem is
> that Letter is wider, but shorter than A4, the change page size only
> works if both new sided are at least the original size, in this case,
> one side would be smaller. In the first step, you size the pages to
> the height of an A4 page and the width of a letter page, and in the
> second step you crop the page to the target A4 size.